# Audio input source in EZAudio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, ezaudio

I am using **EZAudio** to record an audio and plot its audio graph.

How can I record an audio with headphone's mic and with iPhone's microphone simultaneously ?

I want to take input from both the input sources. 
How can I achieve this by using **EZAudio**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to record from several inputs. In iOS you have pair of input/output for current audio session and you could record only from input of that pair.